# python - argparse multiple command-line how to know

Tags: python, arguments, command-line-arguments, argparse

I want to use the argparser module with multiple command-line and some of them should have no arguments.

Example:

```
  parser.add_argument('-website', type=str, nargs='*')
  parser.add_argument('-auth', type=str, nargs='*')
  parser.add_argument('-dothis', action='store_true')
```

So I want to call in a command line following commands:

```
 - python script.py -website www.website.com www.website2.com -dothis
```

In this case the -dothis command should only be use for the second website not for the first one, but it is used for both websites.

Another example:

```
 -python script.py -website www.website1.com www.website2.com -auth username/password
```

In this case the second website has a authentication not the first one.

So what I want is:

```
- python script.py www.webstie1.com -dothis www.website2.com -auth u:p -dothis www.website3.com -auth u:p www.website4.com
```

or:

```
 - python script.py -site www.website1.com -auth u:p -site www.website2.com -site www.website3.com -auth u2:p2
```

so how my script knows which auth is for which website?

How can I fix it?

Comment: Why don't you just call the script twice, with the different sets of arguments? What's the point of this script?

Comment: @jonrsharpe because I want just to run it once everyday.

Comment: I'm not sure a standard command-line interface can help you, then.

Comment: Your examples use a mix of `-site`, '-website' and 'website' (optionals with different names and/or positional) to enter the names.

Comment: What kind of `usage` messge would you like to see?

Answer (score 0):

Your examples are inconsistent.  One has '-website' with 2 values, an other has '-site' repeated (append action?), and the third repeated positionals.

Your goal runs into several fundamental issues with argparse:

- optionals are parsed in an order independent manner
- arguments normally don't interact
- `usage` does not have provision for displaying interactions

I can write a set of custom Action classes that perform the kind of interaction that you want.  But are you really interested?

The basic parsing strategy of `argparse` is to handle the 'positionals' in order, but 'optionals' (flagged) arguments can occur in any order.  So the resulting `args` namespace does not have information about the order of the commands strings.  Old parsers like `getopt` and `optparse` aren't much better, since they focus on collecting the optionals, and returning the rest as a undifferentiate list.

An alterantive to custom Action classes is to parse `sys.argv` yourself.  Just iterate through the strings.  A string without '--' is a site; any '--' flags the follow apply to that site, etc.

A twist on your desired API is to define '--website' as an `append` that takes multiple arguments.

```
parser.add_argument('--website','-w','--site',dest='site',nargs='+',action='append',
   help='website plus flags; may repeat')
```

possible commandlines and Namespaces:

```
--site www.webwsite.com dothig --site www.website2.com
NS(site=[['www.website.con','dothis'],['website2']])

--site site1 username/pass --site site2
NS(site=[['site1','username/pass'],['site2']])
```

So for each element in `args.site`, you can interpret the 1st item as the site name, a parse the rest to find the `dothis` flag and the `auth` name.